# Use AlertDialog with canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-alertdialog

I am using a .java which implements surfaceView to draw in the screen with canvas instead of using a .xml layout file, but I would like to know if somehow at some point (when what i do in the view is completed) its possible to associate this view with the layout file or to call a button or alerdialog.

To be clearer, something like when you win or fail in a game to show up an alerDialog like "you lose" or similar.

Main_Activity looks like:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    activity_layout_animation animation;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            animation = new activity_layout_animation(this);
            setContentView(animation);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            animation.pause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            animation.resume();
          }
```

Some piece of code of view file:

```
    public class activity_layout_animation extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

boolean CanDraw = false
        public activity_layout_animation(Context context){
            super(context);
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    }
       @Override
        public void run(){
  while(CanDraw){

            if ( !surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }
    }
}
```

edit: I can add somethig like this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    }
    builder.setTitle("Delete entry")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with delete
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
```

but it just works in  `public activity_layout_animation(Context context){` and i want to add it in `run()`

Comment: AlertDialog should  work all right, no matter whether you load content view from xml, or create content in the code. Did you try calling AlertDialog?

Answer (score -1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogCoordinate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_coordinates, null);
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogCoordinate);

        ImageView imgShowCoordinates = (ImageView) dialogCoordinate.findViewById(R.id.imgShowCoordinates);
        imgShowCoordinates.setImageResource(R.drawable.whitetrans);
//        int width = dmsUtility.getScreenSize(activity)[0];
//        int height = dmsUtility.getScreenSize(activity)[1];
        Log.d("Coordinate", "showCoordinates: "+arrayList.get(pos).getComment());

        if (arrayList.get(pos).getComment() != null && !arrayList.get(pos).getComment().isEmpty()
                && !arrayList.get(pos).getComment().equals("null")) {
            String[] parts1 = arrayList.get(pos).getComment().split("[\\s\\,]+");
            Log.d(TAG, "getBody: " + arrayList.get(pos).getComment());
            float[] numbers = new float[parts1.length];

            for (int p = 0; p < numbers.length; p++) {
                numbers[p] = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(parts1[p]) * 1000) / 1000f;
            }

            bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imgShowCoordinates.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            if (bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled()) {
                Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 300, 300, true);
                tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
                canW = tempBitmap.getWidth();
                canH = tempBitmap.getHeight();

                for (int q = 0; q < numbers.length; q = q + 4) {
                    float x1 = (canW / 300) * numbers[0 + q];
                    if (numbers.length > q + 2) {
                        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); // Text Color
                        paint.setStrokeWidth(1f); // Text Size
                        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                        float y1 = (canH / 300) * numbers[1 + q];
                        float x2 = (canW / 300) * numbers[2 + q];
                        float y2 = (canH / 300) * numbers[3 + q];
                        tempCanvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: It is not considered good practice just to toss some code without any explanation. Could you please add some explanation to your code?